# rsyslogd vs auditd? Are they alternatives or complement each other?

Tags: linux, logging, syslogd, auditd

I see that both auditd and rsyslogd services are running (on my OpenSuse Leap 15 box). A quick google didn't give a good answer.

Are these services doing the same job? i.e. Could i get rid of one of them and configure the another one to log the same events?

Or do they complement each other? I.e. one is longing some events that other doesn't.

Or are they somehow interdependent? I.e. one doesn't function without the other?

Maybe someone know a good article explaining Linux auditing/log collection options and differences between them and how Linux auditing works in general?

Comment: System Event Logs and Audit Logs are not the same thing. Similar? Yes. Same? No. Apparently events from the Audit Logs can be redirected (or duplicated) to the System Logs, to ease review of all system logs.

Comment: @music2myear thank you, but it leaves me confused. If auditd logs events, such as user logons, user access, user executed commands, accessed files, etc. and auditd logs it all independently, without any help from rsyslogd, what does rsyslogd does?

Maybe I should have asked my question a bit differently. I suppose I should have asked what is the purpose and function of auditd and what is the function and purpose of rsyslogd?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/rsyslogd.8.html and http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/auditd.8.html

Comment: And here, which actually notes some of the unique aspects of auditd https://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/01/a-brief-introduction-to-auditd/